# Python Context Manager to restore a variable's value?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

How would you write a context manager to restore a variable to its original value? For example:

```
x = 5
with Restorer(x):
   x = 6
   ...
print(x)
```

Output would be:
     5

Comment: This would be easier for mutable types, e.g. `list`. Why do you need this?

Comment: It would be as a convenience pattern to avoid a potential mistake.

Comment: You could just use a different name in the block, or extract to a function.

Comment: The python call stack looks after the context of local names for you in a stack frame. Just create a new scope by calling a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible under particular circumstances. Usually the context manager only gets the value (actually a reference) of `x`. It gets no access to the variable itself.

For global variables if the calling function is defined in the same module (or the code is just placed in the same module without surrounding function) the call can be written as

```
with Restorer('x'):
```

Then the restorer can be something like (error checking omitted):

```
class Restorer:

    def __init__(self, varName):
        self.varName = varName

    def __enter__(self):
        self.oldValue = globals()[self.varName]

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        globals()[self.varName] = self.oldValue
```

Comment: @PeterWood In this special case, a call like `with Restorer('x'):` may work.

Comment: @PeterWood Ok, no.

Comment: Yes, this is on the right track. I saw @PeterWood's post and tried this, and yes, it works for globals. I'm interested to know if we can generalize it more?

I assume there is no "reference to variable" hidden away in some obscure python module that could be used?

Comment: Short of introspecting the source code, no. Python simply lacks the type of ad-hoc scope that provides what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing `contextlib.contextmanager`, you can reassign `x` to its original value after the `yield` statement:

```
import contextlib

x = 5
@contextlib.contextmanager
def Restorer(val):
  yield 
  global x
  x = val

print(x)
with Restorer(x):
  x = 6
  print('in contextmanager:', x)

print('outside contextmanager', x)
```

Output:

```
5
in contextmanager: 6
outside contextmanager 5
```

Comment: I suppose `val` as a parameter is redundant. Just do `global x; val = x; yield; x = val`

Comment: This would require a new definition for each variable you would want to restore, as well as only working for a *global* name, not whichever name is currently in scope.

Comment: @PeterWood You could replace it with `global x; old_val = x; yield; x = old_val`, but that's not really better or worse, just different. (I see you had the same thing in mind after you edited your comment.)

Comment: @PeterWood That is true, however, I created the parameter `val` to correspond to the OP's  example

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse a `class` statement to introduce a temporary "scope":

```
x = 5
class Foo:
    print(x)
    x = 6
    print(x)
print(x)
```

This "works" because `Foo` doesn't establish a true new scope, meaning the first `print(x)` refers to the currently in-scope name `x`, but the assignment in a temporary no-man zone in preparation to create a class attribute by the same name, and that attribute is used for the remainder of the body. However, that is, I believe, sufficient to simulate what you are asking for.

(That said, don't actually use this in practice. Write proper functions, or save values manually, if you need some sort of temporary override.)

Answer (score 0):

This is more to do with the scope of names than variables.

You can create scope by creating a function with the behaviour for the block:

```
def behaviour():
    x = 6
    ...

x = 5
behaviour()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
5
```

Alternatively, you could just introduce a new name:

```
x = 5
y = 6
...
print(x)
```

Output:

```
5
```